# Laravel 5 passing value from a controller to a redirected route is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a registration form. I am submitting the form to register. It's working fine. but after the registration I want to send the user to another view that will say an email has been sent to your `$user->email`. but it is not working showing that the user is not defined in view.
Here is my code of creating user:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/register')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }
    $confirmation=$this->createConfirmation_code();
    $user = new User;
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->username = $request->username;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = $request->password;
    $user->country = $request->country;
    $user->street = $request->street;
    $user->zip = $request->zip;
    $user->state = $request->state;
    $user->city = $request->city;
    $user->state = $request->city_state;
    $user->institute = $request->institute;
    $user->confirmation_code=$confirmation;
    $user->confirmed='no';
    $this->sendEmailReminder($request,$user);
    $user->save();
   return redirect('/confirm')->with('user',$user);
}
```

I have a route to find the redirected page

```
    Route::get('/confirm',function(){
    return view('user.confirm');
});
```

Can anyone help me how can I pass the `$user` variable to my view `user.confirm` so that the page can find it?

Comment: just thought, if answers not working and still get the error means,  `user.confirm` page may consist any `{{$user->some}}`. It may give you the error as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
redirect('/confirm')->with('user',$user);
```

And in the view just do the following using blade

```
{{session('user')->email}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// It means that you flashed data to the session    
redirect('/confirm')->with('user',$user); 


// Then you can flash the email value
redirect('/confirm')->with('email', $user->email);


// And retrieve it in blade with 
{{ session('$email') }}
```

See [Redirecting With Flashed Session Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly return view after successful registeration like:
Instead of return redirect place this code:

return view::make('user.confirm', compact('user'));